# How to fix this code output to be like homework sample

Tags: python

I have homework to code calculator and the result must be the only integer
but the problem is it has space between two results I want 4, 2 but it has shown 4 ,  2

```
"""Plus Minus Connected"""
def main():
    fnumber = float(input())
    snumber = float(input())
    print(int(fnumber + snumber), ", ", int(fnumber - snumber))
main()
```

example 2,2.5 output = 4 ,  0
but i want output = 4, 0
how to fix it

Comment: Try this `print(int(fnumber + snumber) + ", " + int(fnumber - snumber))`

Comment: you can also do `print("{}, {}".format(int(fnumber+snumber), int(fnumber-snumber)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below,

```
print(str(int(fnumber) + int(snumber))+", "+str(int(fnumber) - int(snumber)))
```